# Unable to install Twine

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, cryptography, twine

I am running on a Raspberry PI OS

```
uname -a

Linux gus 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have built my (Python) wheel.  I am attempting to publish to testPyPI.

I cannot install Twine - because the `cryptography` module keeps failing.  From my Googling, it's failing because it's packaged as a SDIST ...which means I need to compile it.  Sadly, it is written in Rust.  I tried two things:
1 set this environment variable folks were pointing out worked (I think to bypass and just get a wheel) `export CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`  But this didn't do anything.  So I installed rustc The latest is restc 1.41.1.

BUT - NOW I get

```
          =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      
      error: Rust 1.41.1 does not match extension requirement >=1.48.0
```

How can I get twine to install?  NOTE:  I have the latest version of PIP installed pip 22.3.1.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well...there was no wheel i could find so i finally got the build working.  It took about a day.